# Retrieve Name From Resource File (RESX) in C#

Tags: c#

How to retrieve name and value from Resource file in C# (`RESX`)? For example if I have Resource file with name "MimeTypes" and if I want to  to retrieve name `jpeg` and the return value to be `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Why dont you just let the Resx Custom Tool code generator do its work and use the static class properties that are generated by the tool?

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying. Can you give me some page to read for what this is about ?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, when you add a Resx file to a project, VS will give that file a Custom Tool that will generate class with bunch of static properties that you can use to access value of every resx entry. Go to property browser for resx file and you should have "Custom Tool" filled with PublicResXFileCodeGenerator. But if this resx is not part of your of project then see Tejas answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ResxResourceReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx).

```
using (var resourceReader = new ResxResourceReader("foo.resx"))
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resourceReader)
    { 
        string key = resource.Key.ToString(); 
        string value = resource.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using System.Resources as namespace but I couldn't found ResXResourceReader. What else should I do to find this class ?

Comment: You need to reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. It might not be referenced by default.